# the getContentResolver() method is does not execute

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

> I am trying to insert a row into my database using
> getContentResolver() method. I don't know why it is not getting
> invoked. I see it by looking to log msgs written before and after it.
> the log msg before the given code is appearing while the next on is
> not.
>
> values is the object of my ContentValues class.

```
Uri uri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(petEntry.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

I tried to see if it is returning any value of not using again I am not seeing any Toast msg as the result.

```
if (uri == null) {
            // If the new content URI is null, then there was an error with insertion.
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_insert_pet_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast.
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_insert_pet_successful),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

> I want the row should be inserted to the table using this method.

Comment: Why do you have a `ContentProvider`? Are you expecting other apps to modify the content of your database? If not, I **strongly** recommend that you remove the `ContentProvider` and work with the database more directly.

Comment: I am just trying to learn it, its for learning purpose.